# django how to edit manyTomany inline on form?

Tags: django, web

I would like to store groups of pages under different tags. So I create these models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pages = models.ManyToManyField(Page)
```

I would then like to create a model form(set?) that will allow me to edit the tag, and every page attached to that tag, as one big form. I believe this is what happens when you use Model Inline Formset, but that uses foreign keys. This is a reusable app, right now I'm just rendering the form in a template, but I would prefer to use django forms so it's easier to reuse.

I can't seem to figure out how this is done, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django-tagging](https://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) application.